# Using rails partials to render Bootstrap modal generates multiple modal backdrops in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have multiple rails views sharing a same Bootstrap modal, and I would like to render it using partials `<%= render 'shared/modal' =>` in my `layout/application.html.erb`.

When i visit one of the views first time, the modal works perfectly fine. However, subsequent visits to other views which share the same modal partial will generate multiple modal backdrops, which darkens the background. As follows:

first visit, which is fine:

`<div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>`

subsequent visit on the views which share the same partial:

```
<div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>
<div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>
<div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>
....
<div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>
```

The modal-backdrop div doesn't go away when I route to different views and trigger the modal. I am new to rails and not sure what happens, I tried to search for solution online, and none helps, any help would be much appreciated.

This is my model partial:

```
<div aria-hidden='true' class='modal fade' id='modal' role='dialog' tabindex='-1'>
  <div class='modal-dialog'>
    <div class='modal-content'>
      <div class='modal-header'>
        ...
      </div>

      <div class='modal-body'>
        ...
      </div>

      <div class='modal-footer'>
        ....
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and my `layout/application.html.erb`:

```
<body>
  <%= yield %>
  <%= render 'share/modal' %>
</body>
```

Comment: can you share your javascript code and how you are rendering body of this modal

Answer (score -1):

Check if there are more modals in your views which generate multiple backdrops. Try to use different class name in one view.